# OpenERP Function python

Tags: python, odoo

I want to do on the writing process. I have created e new field in the tree  view '**' Total Caisse'**'. I want to show the same total existing **' Montant'** , but if journal id **''Journal des achats "**  Total negative shows

For example

- if Montant = 500

like the photo 
[image]

[image]

this true function

```
 def _amount_compute(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context, where =''):
    if not ids: return {}
    cr.execute( 'SELECT move_id, SUM(debit) '\
                'FROM account_move_line '\
                'WHERE move_id IN %s '\
                'GROUP BY move_id', (tuple(ids),))
    result = dict(cr.fetchall())
    for id in ids:
        result.setdefault(id, 0.0)
    return result
```

this my function

```
    def _caisse _compute(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context, where =''):
    if not ids: return {}
    cr.execute( 'SELECT journal_id,SUM(debit) *-1 '\
                'FROM account_move_line '\
                'WHERE journal_id =2 '\
                'GROUP BY journal_id', (tuple(ids),)) 
    result = dict(cr.fetchall()) 
    for id in ids:
        result.setdefault(id, 0.0)
    return result
```

Comment: You will get better responses to questions if you can narrow it down to some specific code/lines and to explicitly ask a question about one particular thing. As explained in the guides, [don't just copy in your entire program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry but i cant understand your english

Comment: think for your answer | look the picture  ( je veut afficher le même mentant de total mais different lors de changement de journals id

Comment: still unclear, that is the real question (your question is hard to understand because of bad english) and post error message to, expected output and the output what you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is still unclear for us.

Regrading:**if journal id ''Journal des achats " Total negative shows**

Correct your query by replacing  `SELECT journal_id,SUM(debit) *-1 '` with `SELECT journal_id,SUM(debit)'` Like:

```
 cr.execute( 'SELECT journal_id,SUM(debit)'\
                'FROM account_move_line '\
                'WHERE journal_id =2 '\
                'GROUP BY journal_id', (tuple(ids),))
```

I hope it may help in your case.

Comment: think for your answer